# Meaning in this Line

Tags: android

Im creating an Itemized Map Overlay for my map used in an app im creating. In a tutorial that I am following it uses the following lines:

```
public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
{
...
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
...
}
```

My question is this; what does the brackets part actually mean? It that passed as a parameter to the ItemizedOverlay class? Does the <> brackets actually mean 'instanceof'? Im just looking for a-bit of clarity and understanding of the code Im trying to use so I can manipulate it better later.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Brackets < and > are used for generic types, see [page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList < T > is a generic class that can be an array list over various classes.

ArrayList < OverlayItem > is an array list over OverlayItem